# Reveal a div after x seconds, and reveal another div after y seconds

Tags: javascript, html

I am very new to this, but I'm attempting to reveal div1 after 1 second, and reveal div2 after 5 seconds. At the moment, only div2 is displaying after 1 second. Please help me fix the javascript.

I'd also like to know how to hide div1 after div2 is displayed.

My code:

```
<div id="div1" style="visibility: hidden">Reveal Div 1 after 1 second</div>
<div id="div2" style="visibility: hidden">Reveal Div 2 after 5 seconds</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function showIt() {
  document.getElementById("div1").style.visibility = "visible";
}
setTimeout("showIt()", 1000); // after 1 sec

function showIt() {
  document.getElementById("div2").style.visibility = "visible";
}
setTimeout("showIt()", 5000); // after 5 secs
</script>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot have 2 function with the same name. Change second part to

```
function showIt2() {
  document.getElementById("div2").style.visibility = "visible";
}
setTimeout("showIt2()", 5000); // after 5 secs
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/W9YU5/

Comment: Perfect! How can I hide div1 when div2 is revealed?

Comment: Just add to `function showIt2()` code `document.getElementById("div1").style.visibility = "hidden";`

Comment: Very good! Is it possible for div2 to replace div1 in the same position, rather than under the hidden div1?

Comment: Yes it is possible. For styles of both DIVs instead of `visibility: hidden` use `display: none` and instead of `visibility: visible` use `display: block` (make same adjustments to JavaScript code as well)

Answer (score 0):

Two problems.

1. Each function must have a distinct name.
2. You call a function in setTimeout like `setTimeout(showIt, 5000); // after 5 secs`

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/BcHg6/1/)**

Comment: This works great but is there a way to make it fade in smoothly instead of choppy?

Comment: @LarsMartinson You could either use CSS animations or jQuery