# JavaScript functions not executed in the right order with sleep

Tags: javascript, html

I want to hide an element, and display a new element after one second,

here's the simplified code :

```js
function sleep(milliseconds) {
  var start = new Date().getTime();
  for (var i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) {
    if ((new Date().getTime() - start) > milliseconds){
      break;
    }
  }
}



function loadNewSubmenu()
{
    document.getElementById("content-1").className = "hide-part";
    sleep(1000);
    document.getElementById("content-2").className = "show-part";
}
```

```css
.hide-part{
  display : none;
}
```

```html
<button id="content-1" class="show-part">B1</button>
<button id="content-2" class="hide-part">B2</button>
<button onclick="loadNewSubmenu()">click me</button>
```

**What I expected :**

- Hide the element `#content-1`
- Wait one second
- Show the element `#content-2`

**But this is what i got :**

- One second wait
- Element `#content-1` changed
- Element `#content-2` changed

I know that I can use `setTimeout` to fix it, but what's the reason behind this behavior?

Comment: Don't use `sleep` but `setTimeout`. And you have two elements with same ID, that's wrong.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the JavaScript version of sleep()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/951021/what-is-the-javascript-version-of-sleep)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reveal a div after x seconds, and reveal another div after y seconds](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18808383/reveal-a-div-after-x-seconds-and-reveal-another-div-after-y-seconds) or [CSS Auto hide elements after 5 seconds](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21993661/css-auto-hide-elements-after-5-seconds)

Comment: @Andreas Actually I just want to know why JavaScript execute `sleep()` first, then the `document.getElementById().classname`, I misasked the question

Comment: @Aria I misasked the question, I wanted to know why JavaScript execute sleep() first, then the document.getElementById().classname

Comment: You tell the browser to remove a class which requires an update/redraw of the DOM. But this update is blocked by your `sleep()`. The browser is only able to update the DOM after he finished the `sleep(1000)`. Just use a correct implementation as mentioned in the duplicate.

Comment: Ok, thanks @Andreas

Comment: @PascalGoldbach, You should never use sleep in UI thread,it blocks the ui thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use  **setTimeout** instead of **sleep**

```js
function loadNewSubmenu()
{
    document.getElementById("content-1").className = "hide-part";
    setTimeout(function(){  document.getElementById("content-2").className = "show-part"; },1000);
   
}
```

```css
.hide-part{
  display : none;
}
```

```html
<button id="content-1" class="show-part">B1</button>
<button id="content-2" class="hide-part">B2</button>
<button id="content-3" onclick="loadNewSubmenu()">click me</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You  can use `setTimeout();` Here is an exemple :`

```
<script>
    function loadNewSubmenu()
        {
            document.getElementById("content-1").className = "hide-part";

            setTimeout(function(){
                document.getElementById("content-2").className = "show-part";
            },1000);
        }
</script>`
```

Answer (score 0):

simply use [`setTimeout()`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwievvid0ezTAhUIr48KHTpGA-YQFgglMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3schools.com%2Fjsref%2Fmet_win_settimeout.asp&usg=AFQjCNG2m6mX9BpsbQU38jRA2qXTQq_Jrw)

```js
function loadNewSubmenu() {
  document.getElementById("content-1").className = "hide-part";
  setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById("content-2").className = "show-part";
  }, 1000)
}
```

```css
.hide-part {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button id="content-1" class="show-part">B1</button>
<button id="content-2" class="hide-part">B2</button>
<button id="content-1" onclick="loadNewSubmenu()">click me</button>
```